# Angular Material datepicker value format

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

I have a Datepicker input like this:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #startDate matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateInput)="first($event.value)" placeholder="Enter date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

When the input changes, the *first* funtion receives the `$event.value` date in this format:

> Tue Apr 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200

And I need this one (AAAA-MM-DD):

> 2019-04-09

Is there any way to change the Datepicker's output value whitout parsing it by hand? Thanks.

Comment: You mean without using the JavaScript Date method? No, I don't think so. You can check the api at [Angular Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

Answer (score 3):

With Material `DatePicker`, you could choose `MatNativeDateModule` or `MatMomentDateModule` as date implementation. In your case, I suggest you take the `MatMomentDateModule`, at that time the `$event.value` will be a [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) object, which could be easily converted to a string.

Here is my solution

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule
  ]
```

**your.component.ts**

```
<input #startDate matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateInput)="first($event.value.format('YYYY-MM-D'))" placeholder="Enter date">
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gn2fjf).

Answer (score 2):

You could use DatePipe.

In your component:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe : DatePipe)
{

}
this.datePipe.transform(your_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
```

You must add also in app.module.

I hope this help you!

Comment: 1. Angular already has a date pipe
2. Even if your solution fits what he is looking for, and it works, you didn't show him how to use the pipe.
3. Pipes do not work with values passed in from template to component through a function expression in angular

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom format template for example

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};
```

This will be your format and you will have to import it in your component providers

```
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material';

  //...

providers: [
   {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
 ],
```

I hope this will help you.